# Its a Simple Java HashMap, How elements added in respective buckets

Tags: java, hashmap, collision-detection, collision

Its a Simple Java HashMap, How elements added in respective buckets. I'm aware of the fact of HashMap resizing and collision resolution and good distribution helps in better performance.

1. Out of initial capacity 0 to 15, 6 buckets are occupied for these 10 elements where each Key hashcode of these 10 elements are unique. How it selects the bucket and collide.
2. What happens in resizing & retrieval ?

   ```
   Map<String, String> hmap = new HashMap();

   hmap.put("One", "One");
   hmap.put("Two", "Two");
   hmap.put("Three", "Three");
   hmap.put("Four", "Four");
   hmap.put("Five", "Five");

   hmap.put("Six", "Six");
   hmap.put("Seven", "Seven");
   hmap.put("Eight", "Eight");
   hmap.put("Nine", "Nine");
   hmap.put("Ten", "Ten");
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `HashMap` with 16 buckets. Since it's a **Hash**Map, you start by getting the `hashCode()` of the key, which returns an `int` value.

How do you assign a full range of `int` values to 16 buckets? One way is to use the `%` remainder operator.

However, division is (relatively) slow, so the HashMap implementation makes sure that the number of buckets is always an exponent of 2 (16, 32, 64, 128, ...), so it can use bit-masking instead. To mask, you use bitwise `&` (AND) operator with `buckets - 1`.

So, using your `hmap` (actually, a `LinkedHashMap` to retain the order), you can see the bucket calculation here:

```
System.out.println("Key      Hash Code        Bucket");
System.out.println("======= ==========        ======");
for (String key : hmap.keySet())
    System.out.printf("%-7s %10d & 15 = %d%n", '"' + key + '"', key.hashCode(), key.hashCode() & 15);
```

*Output*

```
Key      Hash Code        Bucket
======= ==========        ======
"One"        79430 & 15 = 6
"Two"        84524 & 15 = 12
"Three"   80786814 & 15 = 14
"Four"     2195782 & 15 = 6
"Five"     2190034 & 15 = 2
"Six"        83138 & 15 = 2
"Seven"   79777773 & 15 = 13
"Eight"   66953327 & 15 = 15
"Nine"     2428114 & 15 = 2
"Ten"        83965 & 15 = 13
```

There are a fair number of collisions here, in buckets 2, 6, and 13.

The buckets shown here doesn't match what you see in the debugger, because `HashMap` applies some extra tricks to attempt to create a better distribution, but this is the essential logic applied.

If the HashMap is re-sized to 32 buckets (next exponent of 2), the result will be:

```
Key      Hash Code        Bucket
======= ==========        ======
"One"        79430 & 31 = 6
"Two"        84524 & 31 = 12
"Three"   80786814 & 31 = 30
"Four"     2195782 & 31 = 6
"Five"     2190034 & 31 = 18
"Six"        83138 & 31 = 2
"Seven"   79777773 & 31 = 13
"Eight"   66953327 & 31 = 15
"Nine"     2428114 & 31 = 18
"Ten"        83965 & 31 = 29
```

As you can see, the keys are moved to other buckets, and there is less collision here, in buckets 6 and 18.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas for you detailed explained :) It helps !!

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` uses [`Object#hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) as the linked Javadoc notes *Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).* To see the values, simply call `hashCode()` on your keys. Something like,

```
String[] keyArray = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
for (String key : keyArray) {
    System.out.printf("%s - %d%n", key, key.hashCode());
}
```

Which outputs (here)

```
One - 79430
Two - 84524
Three - 80786814
Four - 2195782
Five - 2190034
Six - 83138
Seven - 79777773
Eight - 66953327
Nine - 2428114
Ten - 83965
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Elliott, While debugging i could see Keys "Seven" & "Ten" are in 12th index of hashmap bucket. Its hash values are 79776556 & 83964. How these both chooses this 12th index.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap uses hashcode and take and (&)  with it. which means if your hashcode is 12345 it takes & with 15(i-e Number of buckets -1).
Simply you can take all your keys to do something like this to see what it is doing at backend 
        **"System.out.println("Four".hashCode()& 15);"**